# SSH and Telnet connection

Tags: ssh, telnet

I am new to Python and I am developing an application for Telnet and SSH connections, what I want to achieve is to make a function that allows me to validate if the connection is Telnet or SSH, that is, when I make the call to the Host by telnet, if it does not connect, evaluate the SSH option, since some of the router I am accessing are connected by telnet and others by SSH

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: The place to start is to read the specification for both protocols and compare the handshakes. If the server starts the handshake in either protocol, that's the one you want to check for first, because you can wait and see what you receive as a client. If as a client you need to initiate the handshake yourself, then you'll need to try the first one, and hang up and start a new connection to switch to the other. But don't expect us to do this for you -- read the specifications yourself, make a good-faith effort to write the code yourself, ask only about a specific problem if you get stuck.

Comment: Esteban Newell,
execute several If, using variables, ports, but it did not work for me to execute either the telnet script or the SSH script, I only need is guidance that you advise me to do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.